# Datevalue in excel

Tags: excel, vba

can I set my own datevalue (I mean the return value is not from 01/01/1900) in excel formula or vba.? for example: 01/01/2019 is 001 or #1  then 02/01/2019 go for 002 or #2 till end of the year 2019. from the beginning of the next year 2020 it will reset to 001 or #1.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=TODAY()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,0)
```

with proper formatting; or if **A1** contained a date in standard Excel, in another cell:

```
=A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0)
```

**EDIT#1:**

To get the formula cell to display the proper number of leading zeros, apply a custom format of *000*:

[image]

Comment: it's not working. excel ask me to correct the formula "=A1-DATE(2019*(A1),1,0)" after correction it give me an error #NUM!.
pls make this work for me.

Comment: @mohammadIlyas It works. Don't put the formula into `A1` use any other cell and write a valid date into `A1`.

Comment: it works perfectly, first time I made a mistake that I wrote year in number. now everything fine. thank u so much. i have another problem to solve.
the return value is 1 if 01/01/2019. I need to make 3 digits serial number. if 1 with 2 leading zeros, if 11 with a leading zero, if 111 no zeros. pls respond this I am so glad of ur help. thanks

Comment: it works perfectly, first time I made a mistake that I wrote year in number. now everything fine. thank u so much. i have another problem to solve.
the return value is 1 if 01/01/2019. I need to make 3 digits serial number. if 1 with 2 leading zeros, if 11 with a leading zero, if 111 no zeros. pls respond this I am so glad of ur help. thanks

Comment: @mohammadIlyas See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: hi, that's great if I used only number in a cell "B1"(as shown in ur screenshot). I am using few text also. so my code is ="LTL"&A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0)
I tried concatenate between 2 cells also replace the leading zero.